# Calling apply with an array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I found an article that use the following nodeJs function:

```
var path = require('path');

var _root = path.resolve(__dirname, '..');

function root(args) {
    args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
    return path.join.apply(path, [_root].concat(args));
}

exports.root = root;
```

As I didn't know how to use `call` and `apply`, I did some tests/researches, but there's still something I don't get: the `return` statement.

I tried to replace it by

```
return path.join([_root].concat(args))
```

But I got:

> throw new TypeError('Path must be a string. Received ' +
>   inspect(path));

Okay, so the argument passed to `path.join` must be a `string`, fair enough, but the `apply` function passes it as an array, so how could it work?

To verify this, I created this simple function:

```
function foo (arg) { console.log(arg); }
```

And I called it this way:

```
foo.apply(foo, ["plop", "plip"])
```

But I just get "plop", so I don't understand how `path.join` is working if it only gets the first item of the array. I also try to display `arguments`, but then I got an array, not a string.

Basically, I don't understand how come that the array passed as an argument gets accepted as a string while it's not when I directly call `path.join`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you have an array of `const arr = [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]`.
When you call `path.join.apply( path, arr )` it gets spread and would be the same as calling
`path.join( 'a', 'b', 'c' )`.

`.apply` spreads the arguments. So your function should look something like `function foo( arg1, arg2 ) { /* ... */ }`

If you want all arguments passed to a function in one variable, use `arguments` like so:

```
function test( arg1, arg2 ) {
  console.log( arg1, arg2 );
  console.log( arguments );
}

test.apply( null, [ 'a', 'b' ] );
```

---

`.call` on the other hand just calls a function with separated arguments.
So in our example here you'd do `test.call( null, 'a', 'b' );`

---

**So why should I use `call` or `apply`?** Well, there might be a lot more reasons than I'm going to mention here, but

1. you can call function dynamically, deciding which one to call based on a variable.
2. you can define another context. The first argument is the context you can pass which is represented as `this` inside the function body.

Here are the document pages for [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) and [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

Comment: Absolutely correct. I wan't just to add, that the only difference between apply and call, is how arguments are passed. Apply - array and call - just comma separated.

Comment: So if I understand well, it works because the array is spread in arguments for `path.join`. But in that case, how does this function access these parameters as their number can be dynamic (`path.join('a', 'b')` or `path.jon('a', 'b', 'c')`). I guess it uses `arguments`, which is an array-like, so why doesn't it work when I directly pass a real array in it ? Is it because in the first case, `arguments` will contain string items and in the second case, it will contain a string array?

Comment: Because `path` is an array. It doesn't use the arguments as input but only the first argument as "glue". Look at the example [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Comment: Sorry but I don't get it... `path` is the node package, not an array.

Comment: Ah, so sorry. You are right. So yes, `path.join` might use the `arguments` variable inside the join function. Or the ES6 rest-statement written like `function text( ...rest ) {}` (you could also write another name instead of `rest`

Comment: I updated my answer. So when you call `path.join.apply( path, arr )` it would be the same as if you'd say `path.join( arr[0], arr[1], ...)`